# Geom_point not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to present some of my math homework in R, the problem is I cannot plot the intersecting points with geom_point. Here is my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)


#function boundaries
x <- -5:5

#left hand function
dat_fun1 <- data.frame(x, y = 2 * sin(x))
fun1 <- function(x) y = 2 * sin(x)

#right hand function
dat_fun2 <- data.frame(x, y = x + cos(x))
fun2 <- function(x) y = x + cos(x)

#both plotted together.
ggplot() +
  geom_function(data = dat_fun1, mapping = aes(x,y), fun = fun1, color = "blue")+
  geom_function(data = dat_fun2, mapping = aes(x,y), fun = fun2, color = "red")+
  geom_point(x = -1.767, y = -1.962)
```

Usually, this format works for me when plotting functions. But, it could be a problem with my R-Studio because I was getting errors and had to update rlang.

Comment: Try `geom_point(aes(x = -1.767, y = -1.962))`.  You need to wrap the `x` and `y` point coordinates within the call to the aesthetics argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have to specify a global or a local `data` argument, e.g. add `data=dat_fun1` to `geom_point` or use `annotate` to add your point(s) which doesn't require the `data` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot() +
  geom_function(data = dat_fun1, mapping = aes(x,y), fun = fun1, color = "blue")+
  geom_function(data = dat_fun2, mapping = aes(x,y), fun = fun2, color = "red")

base +
  geom_point(data = dat_fun1, x = -1.767, y = -1.962, color = "green", size = 10)
```

[image]

```r
base +
  annotate(geom = "point", x = -1.767, y = -1.962, color = "green", size = 10)
```

[image]